# Create mountable disk or partition backups

Tags: hard-drive, backup

I have a few old hard disks (both SATA and IDE) collecting dust. As a data hoarder, I don't want to lose all the information on them. Thus, I'd like to create some backups of all the data on them. I did some investigation, but am unsure what would be the best way to go.

Some criteria for what I'm looking for, ordered from most important to least important:

1. The backups should be future-proof. Thus, I'd prefer to use some open source tools.
2. I'd love to be able to easily look into all the data, i.e. it would be great if I wouldn't have to jump through multiple hoops to mount some disk / partition.
3. At least one of the drives has some hardware issues (takes multiple tries to spin up), so the backup process should be able to handle hardware problems (i.e. unreadable sectors).
4. While I can directly attach the SATA drives, I'll have to use a USB2-to-IDE adapter to attach the IDE drives. I know this will limit the read performance to USB2 levels, but this shouldn't affect the backup process.
5. Must run on Linux (Arch) or Windows 10.
6. The backups should be space efficient, i.e. if the data on the hard drive only used 10 GB of the 250 GB available, then the backup should not be more than 10 GB (or less, e.g. if using additional compression).

I looked into different options like dd, ddrescue, Clonezilla and partclone, but it's hard for me to judge which tool(s) would be best for the job.

What would be the best option(s) given my criteria?

(Using multiple tools would be fine if there is a bigger benefit to that approach. Also, please point out anything I might have forgotten.)

---

Addendum:
Criteria 2 means that it would be preferable to be able to just open all the files directly. However, I would be fine if I had to mount some image first, while having to determine the offsets of a partition I want to mount in a backup file would be less favorable. I know that these tools have some trade-offs, e.g. in the ease of use of the backups etc., which is what I'm looking for input about.

Also, one more criterion - less important than the ability to handle hardware errors (3), more important than an adapter not messing with the backup process(4), so let's call it 3.5:

3.5. Some of the drives contain operating systems with programs / configurations that are hard to recreate, but which are important to open certain files (I recorded some music with old DAWs and old plugins, good luck recreating such a setup 15 years later…). Thus, it would be great to be able to boot into such an OS later (e.g. in a VM, or by copying the data back to a physical disk). I would be fine if additional steps were necessary to be able to do so, but the easier such a process would be, the better.

Comment: Why are you looking at block level rather than file level backups here?  If you are backing up block devices (2) gors out the window unless you write an automounting script.  If you are recovering from a dodgy drive ddrescue is the way to go.

Comment: @davidgo: I added some more information. I think I'd prefer block level backups, but as I'm new to this, I don't know whether there's some other way to achieve criterion 3.5.

Comment: In order to meet crition 3.5 you really do need to do full block images per @user1686 answer.     You can eliminate playing around with offsets by using various tools, losetup, kpartx can do a lot of heavy lifting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest a two-stage process:

1. Use `ddrescue` to reliably create a 1:1 block image of the disk, letting the program deal with any read errors that might occur (ddrescue can retry an interrupted copy when run again with the same "map file" it creates).
2. Once the data is safe, convert the 1:1 image into a more space-efficient format.

   On Linux, attach the entire image using `losetup --partscan` and mount the individual file­systems. (GNOME Disks will just do this automatically.) At this point, if you're dealing with an ordinary data disk, you can just take the files out and put them in a .rar if that's what you prefer.

   But if the disk had an OS installed and you want to keep the full image around  (e.g. to convert it back to a bootable disk), at this point you could run `fstrim` on the mounted filesystems, resulting in a sparse image file that does not occupy the "unused" space (it would still have 250 GB as its *apparent* size, but with the empty areas not actually allocated).

   For Windows, the raw image could be converted to VHD/VHDX format, which is directly mountable on Windows 10+ (just double-click the image to attach it) as well as being more reliably space-efficient (not all filesystems can preserve the "sparseness" of sparse files, whereas there's no problem with putting a .vhd on an exFAT-formatted disk). The `qemu-img` tool might be able to do this. (I would have just used Disk2vhd if the disk was known to be good, but it doesn't deal well with errors.)